# How to sort values in descending order using the min and max function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some homework for a beginner course that I attend. I need help sorting a number of values. I use the input function to enter in 4 random numbers and then I have to use the min() and max() functions to sort the 4 numbers in order of lowest to highest. This is what I have so far

```
first_integer = input("Please enter the first integer: ")
second_integer = input("Please enter the second integer: ")
third_integer = input("Please enter the third integer: ")
fourth_integer = input("Please enter the fourth integer: ")

integers = (first_integer, second_integer, third_integer, fourth_integer)

print ("The integers in increasing order are", sorted((min (integers)) + (max(integers))))
```

When I try and run the command it gives me the lowest and the highest values. How can I fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify something? Your title says you want in descending order. Then in your explanation you want lowest to highest. Which one is it?

Comment: I meant to say ascending. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

To sort a small number of items just using `min` and `max` you can use a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). Here's an implementation of the example sorting network for 4 items at the end of the Introduction section of that Wikipedia article. My code verifies that it works by sorting all 24 permutations of the input list.

```
from itertools import permutations

def sort2(a, b):
    return min(a, b), max(a, b)

def sort4(a, b, c, d):
    a, c = sort2(a, c)
    b, d = sort2(b, d)
    a, b = sort2(a, b)
    c, d = sort2(c, d)
    b, c = sort2(b, c)
    return a, b, c, d

# Test all permutations
for seq in permutations([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print(seq, sort4(*seq))
```

**output**

```
(1, 2, 3, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4, 3) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 2, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 4, 2) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 4, 2, 3) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 4, 3, 2) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 1, 3, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 1, 4, 3) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 1, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 1) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 1, 3) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 3, 1) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(3, 1, 2, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(3, 1, 4, 2) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(3, 2, 1, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(3, 2, 4, 1) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 1, 2) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 2, 1) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(4, 1, 2, 3) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(4, 1, 3, 2) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(4, 2, 1, 3) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(4, 2, 3, 1) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(4, 3, 1, 2) (1, 2, 3, 4)
(4, 3, 2, 1) (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

As Wikipedia mentions, for a small number of items sorting networks are more efficient than other sorting algorithms. However, my code will be slower than using Python's built-in `.sort` method or `sorted` function because they operate at C speed.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have collected the list of numbers (converted to integers or float if applicable) you can effect a sort by picking the largest and smallest items in the list, adding these to 2 separate lists, and then combining the results into a final, sorted, list.

Here is a function that does that using *both* `min()` and `max()`. It sorts the given list in-place:

```
def max_min_sort(l):
    _max = []
    _min = []
    while l:
        n = max(l)
        _max.insert(0, n)
        l.remove(n)
        if l:
            n = min(l)
            _min.append(n)
            l.remove(n)
    l[:] = _min + _max

>>> numbers = [100, 200, 44, 71]
>>> max_min_sort(numbers)
>>> numbers
[44, 71, 100, 200]
```

It's also possible, and more *slightly* more efficient to just use one of `max()` or `min()`. Example using `min()`:

```
def min_sort(l):
    result = []
    while l:
        n = min(l)
        result.append(n)
        l.remove(n)
    l[:] = result
```

Answer (score 1):

@idjaw is right that `min` and `max` are not necessary here, just use `sorted`. But if you are not allowed to use `sorted`, the following code will be one solution.

```
first_integer = input("Please enter the first integer: ")
second_integer = input("Please enter the second integer: ")
third_integer = input("Please enter the third integer: ")
fourth_integer = input("Please enter the fourth integer: ")

integers = [first_integer, second_integer, third_integer, fourth_integer]

result = []
for i in range(len(integers)):
    result.append(min(integers))
    integers.remove(min(integers))
print ("The integers in increasing order are", result)
```

Comment: I need to use both max() and min() functions in my code.

Comment: Also when I run that function it says "'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove'".

Comment: oh, really? There is no tuple involved in the code at all.